# How do I copy the table structure of a postgres table into a different postgres database without the data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to play around with a data syncing program I wrote, but I want to copy the structure of the production database into a new table on my localhost Postgres database, without copying the data to my localhost db.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
TABLE existing_table 
WITH NO DATA;
```

But I am unsure how to modify it to work with 2 different databases.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to the question "how to create the DDL script for a table" which can easily be done using `pg_dump` on the command line.

```
pg_dump -d some_db -h production_server -t existing_table --schema-only -f create.sql
```

The file `create.sql` then contains the CREATE TABLE script that you can run on your local Postgres installation.